I got the flame graph for my python-fastspi application. but i want CPU and Memory usages details by each end-point ho i can get?
[codeguru profiler](https://i.sstatic.net/8SHks.png)
I've successfully set up a profiling group and integrated the profiler agent into my local application. After profiling, I can see a flame graph, but I'm interested in obtaining CPU and Memory usage details for each endpoint in my application.
Is there a way to achieve this using CodeGuru Profiler? I've searched the documentation and haven't found a clear solution. Can someone provide guidance or point me in the right direction on how to gather CPU and Memory usage metrics specifically for each endpoint?
Any help would be greatly appreciated.
